# jquery disabling image when a click event not working

Tags: jquery

```
  $('.input_control').attr('disabled', true);
```

i am doing this for prev or next.prev is image.user click prev img,then it goes to query and load files but here user is clicking continously and it freezes the screen

swap and add some greyed image.i am doing this to prevent continuous click's.
user click image and i disable it and enable it after success load of file.

Answer (score 0):

## Update based on comments:

To load the original image, you can apply `load` event to the image something like this:

```
$('.input_control').load(function(){
   $(this).attr('src', 'path to original image');
});
```

---

You simply need to specify new path to your greyed image using `src` attribute:

```
$('.input_control').attr('src', 'greyed image path');
```

Where `.input_control` is assumed to be the class of image you want to swap the image for.

Comment: i have to bring greyedimage directly from folder.can i do this.

Comment: @user: yes, just specify relative path to your folder example `myfolder/greayed.jpg`

Comment: I have an image,user is clicking it continuously.it is not able to load file so,i want to apply greyed after clicking and add original image after sucess of loading a file.How to do this?

Comment: @user: You can use the `load` event on the image which triggers after image has been loaded, i will update the answer for that.

Comment: i am doing this for prev or next.prev is image.user click prev img,then it goes to query and load files but here user is clicking continously and it freezes the screen.

Answer (score 0):

An image cannot be `disabled`. You will have to swap the image to a new one, by changing the `src` attribute instead of the `disabled` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Change the src of the image to a greyed one.

Or you could add a second image on top of it that is a semi transparant png to add a grey/white overlay. Advantage is that you only need a single image to grey out an entire gallery, and it's less work because you don't need to create greyed versions of all your images. But I'm not sure if it will give you the exact greyed look you want.

Comment: he'll need png fix for some of the ie browsers as png transparency will not work there..

Comment: Yep, my bad, just checked IE7, png works fine with it. Agree on IE6.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is reduce the opacity, this will give you the effect you are looking for without having to generate grayed out images :

```
$('.input_control').fadeTo(100,0.50);
```

The 100 is time 100ms - You can play around with the time to give it a nice fade effect.
 0.50 is opacity1 equal to 100%, 0.50 equal to 50% 
[jQuery fadeTo reference](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) 
(Other functions of intrest are fadeIn & fadeOut -- they work similar to fadeTo, except they hide and show elements rather than make them transparent)

You can also use :

```
$('.input_control').css("opacity",0.50);
```

This will make it opaque again :

```
$('.input_control').fadeTo(100,1);
```

OR

```
$('.input_control').css("opacity",1);
```